# I would like a wallet that lets me export my private keys

Tags: wallet

Multibit classic allows you to export private keys.  Apparently Multibit HD no longer allows this  (is it true?  I'm pretty sure).

I want a wallet that lets me export my private keys.  So I don't have to depend on any specific software program.

I'm not sure I trust Electrum doesn't it rely on it's own network of servers?  I don't want to rely on any specific servers.

Seems like the only way is to get Bitcoin-QT client and have the whole darn blockchain which I have to keep updated.

Does anyone have any suggestions.  I'm starting to think Multibit classic is the only one that can export private keys without needing the whole blockchain.

Comment: I wouldn't try to use mb classic. Lots of issues, especially with sending bitcoin, because it gets the fees all wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Try it with JAXX wallet, I think there you're getting your keys

Comment: While your suggestion might be helpful, it would be really great if you could also answer some of the other questions that were asked :)